# How to keep an object off center while tracking it?

Tags: camera, tracking

I have applied the Track To constraint to a camera in Blender (3.2.2). It tracks the target object. Perfect till here.
But it keeps the object at the center of the frame, while I want to keep the object off center. How do I achieve this?

Comment: you could track an empty instead and parent this empty to your object?